# Ubuntu Server and Tomcat 6 WebApp SecurityUtil Exception

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, web-applications, servlet

I am running clean install of [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition) 9.10 with Tomcat 6 installed from the Ubuntu installation. When I upload a WebApp through the Tomcat Manager and it starts automatically on boot with `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start` my Lib Jars in my Web Apps `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` throw an exception.

I am using [Project ROME](https://rome.dev.java.net/) for my RSS Feed which works fine on my local tomcat server I test on through Eclipse. However, when I run it on the Ubuntu Tomcat I get a ServletException:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not initialize class com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeedImpl
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:294)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
```

I am guessing I need to change one of the files in /etc/tomcat6/policy.d/ which generates the /var/cache/tomcat6/catalina.policy file. But I don't know what to change. Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got something that works.

I edited the /etc/tomcat6/policy.d/01system.policy and added at the bottom:

```
// Grant WebApps All Permission
grant codeBase "file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

This works now, but not sure if its the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the security manager for Tomcat as whole.

Edit `/etc/default/tomcat6` and set `TOMCAT6_SECURITY` to no.

```
TOMCAT6_SECURITY=no
```

(Make sure the line is uncommented)

Be sure you understand the implications of doing this though.